# vb editor is replacing ! with $

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using VBA in Access 2013. I'm trying to reference an Excel range that includes a ! character.  By the time it gets evaluated, it has been changed to a $ character - so my code won't work.

The relevant lines of my code are

```
range = "'" & Page.Name & "'" & "!A:O"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "temp", Source, True, range
```

where the 1st line sets the range variable and the 2nd line uses it.  When I run the code, I get the following error:

[image]

where it seems that the ! has been replaced by a $, causing the error

How can I fix this or workaround the problem with a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing your single quotes from your `range`.

```
range = Page.Name & "!A:O"
```

I was able to reproduce the error, and removing the single quotes cleared it up for me.